# WCF-The document was understood, but it could not be processed

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which i deployed on my test server. Trying to use it on my test project and I added a reference and I get this error

```
    The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8731/somewhere.nowhere.com/service1/?xsd=xsd2'.
  - Unable to connect to remote server
  - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://192.1.1.1/TestService/somewhere.nowhere.com.svc?wsdl'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service .  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I had my test app working before I added wsdlextras to my service project to include wsdl documentation.

This is the schema from my wsdl:

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8731/somewhere.nowhere.com/?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8731/somewhere.nowhere.com/?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestService"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8731/somewhere.nowhere.com/?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8731/somewhere.nowhere.com/?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Attempt to Fix 1:
I changed my

```
<host>
 <baseAddresses>
  <add baseAddress />
 </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

so my addresses in my schema all mmatch up. I can update my service reference on my test project, however I cannot view any of my methods exposed by my wcf service.

My service is deployed on windows 2003 and my test app is on XP as well

Comment: try to ping 192.1.1.1, if you get the result try telnet 192.1.1.1 8731 command to check if you have a connection to server, may be firewall block the connection, are you deploying server on vista?

Answer (score 2):

Answer is here:
[WCF IIS server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673495/wcf-iis-server-configuration)

in short...
The problem was with WCF identity permissions. The identity that is used for the application pool that hosts the WCF service must have full NTFS permissions on the %WINDIR%\temp folder. After changing that permission to my identity (LOCAL SERVICE) on C:\Windows\Temp I was able to add service reference to WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks as if it cannot find the imported xsd file xsd2.

The call to the service looks like it is on port 80, but the include files are referenced from point 8731.