# WCF IIS server configuration

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7, configuration, web-config

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7 on it.  I deployed WCF service on it.  When I specify WCF service address in browser (local or external machine) http://sbkisourcedev01/VCIndex/Calculator.svc?wsdl I am getting service description in browser.  However when I am trying to add reference to the project to that service I am getting following error:

```
The document was understood, but it could not be processed.  

  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://sbkisourcedev01/VCIndex/Calculator.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
  - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
  - Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://sbkisourcedev01/VCIndex/Calculator.svc?wsdl'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://sbkisourcedev01/VCIndex/Calculator.svc?wsdl.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I have this service running on Windows 7 and it is okay.  So I believe there is something with my W2K8 IIS configuration settings.

Here is my config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior"
               name="WCFVCIndex.Calculator">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="WCFVCIndex.ICalculator"
                  bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was with WCF identity permissions.  The identity that is used for the application pool that hosts the WCF service must have full NTFS permissions on the %WINDIR%\temp folder.  After changing that permission to my identity (LOCAL SERVICE) on C:\Windows\Temp I was able to add service reference to WCF service.

Comment: How do you do that? Can you mention these steps?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried http://sbkisourcedev01/VCIndex/mex?

Comment: Thanks for helping.  It did not work.  I got this error:  There was an error downloading 'http://sbkisourcedev01/VCIndex/mex'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://sbkisourcedev01/VCIndex/mex'.