# Unable to add WCF as service reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

[image: WCF Service svc?wsdl]

I cannot add this WCF as Service Reference to my project.

[image]

Here's the details of error occured.

> The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
>     - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
>     - There was an error downloading 'http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
>     - The request was aborted: The operation has timed out. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/Service1.svc?wsdl'. An error occurred while
>   receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/Service1.svc?wsdl. This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
>   occurred on a receive. Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
>   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond If the service is defined
>   in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the
>   service reference again.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the service has enabled the service metadata attribute in the `System.servicemodel` section, the possible reason is WCF identity permission.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

> The identity that is used for the application pool that hosts the WCF
>   service must have pull NTFS permission on the %WINDIR%\temp folder.
>   After changing that permission to my identity (LOCAL SERVICE) on
>   C:\Windows\Temp I was able to add service reference to WCF service.

The answer is here, please refer to the source link.
[WCF IIS server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673495/wcf-iis-server-configuration)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.